# Extra pixels left and top of canvas python turtle

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I'm not sure why but on the left and top of a canvas I'm getting weird behaviour while creating my snake game using turtle. There's a border of 10 pixels on the left and on the top.

Main Code

```
import functools
from turtle import Screen
import time
from Snake import Snake


# initialize screen
win = Screen()
WIDTH = HEIGHT = 800
win.setup(width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT)
win.bgcolor("black")
canvas = win.getcanvas()
root = canvas.winfo_toplevel()
root.overrideredirect(1)
win.tracer(0)

s = Snake()


def main():
    segments = s.init_segments()
    win.update()
    move_keys = ["Right", "Up", "Left", "Down"]
    running = True
    inc = 0

    for k in move_keys:
        win.onkeypress(functools.partial(s.move, segments, inc, k), key=k)
        inc += 90

    win.listen()

    while running:
        win.update()
        time.sleep(0.1)
        s.move(segments, segments[0].heading(), "none")

        if s.crashed(win.window_width(), win.window_height(), segments):
            running = False
            break

    win.exitonclick()


main()
```

Snake Code

```
from turtle import Turtle
class Snake:

    def init_segments(self):
        segs = []
        x_pos = 0
        for i in range(3):
            t = Turtle(shape="square")
            t.color("white")
            t.penup()
            t.speed(1)
            segs.append(t)
            if t != segs[0]:
                x_pos -= 20
                t.goto(x_pos, 0)
        return segs

    def __no_turn(self, h, d):
        if h - d == -180 or h - d == 180:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __no_skip(self, k, dir):
        if (k == "Right" and dir == 0 or k == "Up" and dir == 90
                or k == "Left" and dir == 180 or k == "Down" and dir == 270):
            return False
        else:
            return True

    def move(self, t_list , dir, k):
        for seg_num in range(len(t_list) - 1, -1, -1):
            if self.__no_turn(t_list[0].heading(), dir):
                continue
            elif seg_num > 0:
                if self.__no_skip(k, dir):
                    t_list[seg_num].goto(t_list[seg_num - 1].position())
            else:
                t_list[seg_num].setheading(dir)
                if self.__no_skip(k, dir):
                    t_list[seg_num].forward(20)


    def crashed(self, window_width, window_height, t_list):
        head_position = t_list[0].position()
        body_positions = []
        hw = window_width/2
        hh = window_height/2
        for i in range(len(t_list)):
            body_positions.append(t_list[i].position())

        body_positions.pop(0)
        for i in range(len(body_positions)):
            if head_position == body_positions[i]:
                return True

        if head_position[0] >= hw:
            print(f"Head Position: {head_position[0]} ... Wall Position: {hw}")
            return True

        elif head_position[0] <= -hw:
            print(f"Head Position: {head_position[0]} ... Wall Position: {-hw}")
            return True

        elif head_position[1] >= hh:
            print(f"Head Position: {head_position[1]} ... Wall Position: {hh}")
            return True

        elif head_position[1] <= -hh:
            print(f"Head Position: {head_position[1]} ... Wall Position: {-hh}")
            return True
```

[image: Image showing the black border]

The print lines in this file were added to try and figure out what was going on.

Please help me understand what's going on.

Thanks.

Edit:
Also I didn't notice it earlier, but there's a 1px border on the bottom and right hand sides.

Second Edit to illustrate the problem further.

I added the code for the pills a while ago. What I do is, I spawn every pill in all at once and hide them because you can't destroy a turtle without clearing the screen and it would be weird to get the turtle position every single time and redraw the turtle on the screen where it had been 0.1 seconds previously. Then I got this result.

[image: Problem Illustration]

As you can see the pills are spawning off screen.

The following is the code that I used in order to spawn in all pills and is similar to the code that I use for determining the edges of the screen.

```
hw = int(WIDTH/2)
hh = int(HEIGHT/2)
p_list = []
for i in range(-hw, hw, 20):
    for j in range(-hh, hh, 20):
        p = Pill((i, j))
        p.show_pill(segments)
        p_list.append(p)
```

What happens when I reorder the `win.update()`

[image: Reordered win.update()]

As you can see here, the right side now crashes one whole segment in. If you look closely, you'll see in this picture that the white of the snake, covers the extra pixel of space that is not covered in the previous picture where it stops on the last pixel of the circle.
You'll also see in the second picture and this one that there is a row of circles on the bottom that are peeking over the edge of the window's border.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally figured out why this happens.

First problem: I was previously led to believe that all turtle shapes are created equal. No they're not. While the default size for a turtle might be 20px by 20px, a square and circle are both defaulted to 21px as they need a center point that is not an even number so that it can divide evenly between the 4 quadrants of turtle's co-ordinate system (which has a single pixel serving as the x and y axes).

How to solve:

- Make the canvas a multiple of 21px.
- Remember that the canvas, when split into 2 parts has half of a turtle on each edge, which counts as a full turtle but the turtle only completes over the canvas, so we're sitting with an extra column and row of turtles.
- Remove the last column and row of turtles and move the entire grid over by one turtle.

If done correctly you'll end up with the result below. Unfortunately, 2px at the right and bottom will be cut off as it's used for Turtle's UI. The top and left face a similar problem in that a single row of pixels are used for Turtle's UI

[image: Screenshot of properly aligned circles.]

The snake itself is done in a similar manner in that instead of shifting the starting segment 20px I shift it 11px first and then I appended the other parts of the snake. I calculate it's position by removing the 11px that I shifted it initially. This literally solved most of the problems with the snake apart from stuff that Turtle's ui takes away.

Answer (score 0):

If you move `win.update()` after `s.move(segments, segments[0].heading(), "none")` instead of before it will work (i.e) crash in the same way in all four walls.

If you don't want the head to get burst into the wall when crashing then modify the crash boundary check accordingly.

Comment: Nope, something else is going on. I can post another screenshot with more code to illustrate.

Comment: Sure. The 1 px white part is coming from the TKinter/Turtle interface implementation. Rest, just changing this order as for me should make this to work except this 1px part which you are referring to. Would like to know why this reordering will not help.

Comment: because I did the reorder. I'll show it to you in my edit.

Comment: I got you. Along with the reorder change the boundary check instead of hw check for  (hw-20) for the right wall and so on.

Comment: understand that my aim is to crash only after I get to the edge. If you play snake you'll see that at the edge, pills still spawn which means you get a bit of time in order to turn your snake (I can write code for this (probably)). Secondly, why are the edges of a turtle graphics window not at -hw, hw, -hh, hh? That is the part that I'm trying to understand. Why does it have that border because even when I use your method, my snake crashes 10px away from left and top and 1-2px away from right and bottom. Exactly the same as mine, only it doesn't allow you to turn on the edge.

Comment: Considering python excludes the last value in the range, you might want to write range(-hw, hw+20, 20) to get the exact symmetrical pills you want. Regarding the exact pixel level window alignment you want, I would recommend defining the win.setup as win.setup(width=WIDTH+60, height=HEIGHT+60). Then using a similar approach like pills to draw a boundary brick wall instead of a circle use a square for the wall.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241468/discussion-between-william-and-chamkey).